# storyboard is shown as a xml document. How to switch the view back to default graphical mode?

Tags: storyboard, xcode6

I was trying to link a widget on a view controller in a story board to an IBOutlet variable in the view controller swift file.

However when I switched on the Assistant, the storyboard is switched to a xml code mode, as shown in the screen shot

[image]

How can revert it back to the default graphical mode?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

open the project navigator on the left, select the Main.storyboard, right click, select open as "Interface Builder"